# How to count number of items with same id in csv in Perl

Tags: perl, csv, hash

So I have a CSV file with columns seperated by a :. it sort of looks like this in this format User:groupnumber

```
x:2
y:2
z:4
p:1
q:4
```

So group x would have 2 users in that group, group 4 would have 2 users , group 1 would have 1 user.

What can I user in perl to do this? I cant seem to figure it out. I thought of putting them into a hash but I could not figure out how to count many keys have the same value.

Is a hash the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a hash is the right data structure.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %count;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($user, $group) = split /:/;
    ++$count{$group};
}

for my $group (keys %count) {
    print "Group $group has $count{$group} members.\n";
}

__DATA__
x:2
y:2
z:4
p:1
q:4
```